# How to capture camera's video in real time?

Tags: c++

I'm using Usb 3.0 Basler camera acA640-750uc to capture the video and here is the program to use 2 cameras and grab the frame:

the problem is when i runed this program my computer captured the video from 2 cameras but the video is slower than my actual movement about 2 sec.It means
my video is slower than the real time and I want to capture the video in real time.
How can I solve this problem?

I've tried to change the condition of `for (size_t i = 0; i < cameras.GetSize(); ++i)` from `++i` to `i++`, but it doesn't work.

```
#include <pylon/PylonIncludes.h>
#ifdef PYLON_WIN_BUILD
#include <pylon/PylonGUI.h>
#endif

// Namespace for using pylon objects.
using namespace Pylon;

// Namespace for using cout.
using namespace std;

// Number of images to be grabbed.
static const uint32_t c_countOfImagesToGrab = 1000;

// Limits the amount of cameras used for grabbing.
// It is important to manage the available bandwidth when grabbing with 
// multiple cameras.
// This applies, for instance, if two GigE cameras are connected to the 
// same network adapter via a switch.
// To manage the bandwidth, the GevSCPD interpacket delay parameter and 
// the GevSCFTD transmission delay
// parameter can be set for each GigE camera device.
// The "Controlling Packet Transmission Timing with the Interpacket and 
// Frame Transmission Delays on Basler GigE Vision Cameras"
// Application Notes (AW000649xx000)
// provide more information about this topic.
// The bandwidth used by a FireWire camera device can be limited by 
// adjusting the packet size.
static const size_t c_maxCamerasToUse = 2;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// The exit code of the sample application.
int exitCode = 0;

// Before using any pylon methods, the pylon runtime must be initialized. 
PylonInitialize();

try
{
// Get the transport layer factory.
CTlFactory& tlFactory = CTlFactory::GetInstance();

// Get all attached devices and exit application if no device is found.
DeviceInfoList_t devices;
if (tlFactory.EnumerateDevices(devices) == 0)
{
throw RUNTIME_EXCEPTION("No camera present.");
}

// Create an array of instant cameras for the found devices and avoid 
// exceeding a maximum number of devices.
CInstantCameraArray cameras(min(devices.size(), c_maxCamerasToUse));

// Create and attach all Pylon Devices.
for (size_t i = 0; i < cameras.GetSize(); ++i)
{
cameras[i].Attach(tlFactory.CreateDevice(devices[i]));

// Print the model name of the camera.
cout << "Using device " << cameras[i].GetDeviceInfo().GetModelName() << 
endl;
}

// Starts grabbing for all cameras starting with index 0. The grabbing
// is started for one camera after the other. That's why the images of 
// all
// cameras are not taken at the same time.
// However, a hardware trigger setup can be used to cause all cameras to 
// grab images synchronously.
// According to their default configuration, the cameras are
// set up for free-running continuous acquisition.
cameras.StartGrabbing();

// This smart pointer will receive the grab result data.
CGrabResultPtr ptrGrabResult;
// Grab c_countOfImagesToGrab from the cameras.
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < c_countOfImagesToGrab && cameras.IsGrabbing(); 
++i)
{
cameras.RetrieveResult(5000, ptrGrabResult, 
TimeoutHandling_ThrowException);

// When the cameras in the array are created the camera context value
// is set to the index of the camera in the array.
// The camera context is a user settable value.
// This value is attached to each grab result and can be used
// to determine the camera that produced the grab result.
intptr_t cameraContextValue = ptrGrabResult->GetCameraContext();

#ifdef PYLON_WIN_BUILD
// Show the image acquired by each camera in the window related to each 
// camera.

Pylon::DisplayImage(cameraContextValue, ptrGrabResult);
#endif

// Print the index and the model name of the camera.
cout << "Camera " << cameraContextValue << ": " << 
cameras[cameraContextValue].GetDeviceInfo().GetModelName() << endl;

// Now, the image data can be processed.
cout << "GrabSucceeded: " << ptrGrabResult->GrabSucceeded() << endl;
cout << "SizeX: " << ptrGrabResult->GetWidth() << endl;
cout << "SizeY: " << ptrGrabResult->GetHeight() << endl;
const uint8_t* pImageBuffer = (uint8_t*)ptrGrabResult->GetBuffer();
cout << "Gray value of first pixel: " << (uint32_t)pImageBuffer[0] << 
endl << 
endl;
}
}
catch (const GenericException& e)
{
// Error handling
cerr << "An exception occurred." << endl
<< e.GetDescription() << endl;
exitCode = 1;
}

// Comment the following two lines to disable waiting on exit.
cerr << endl << "Press Enter to exit." << endl;
while (cin.get() != '\n');
// Releases all pylon resources. 
PylonTerminate();

return exitCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not experienced in this field but changing `++i` to `i++` obviously does not solve your problem as they are equivalent in this for definition (`for (size_t i = 0; i < cameras.GetSize(); ++i)`). 
I am not sure but accourding to comments in code you may need to configure cameras manually (cameras may configured differently):

```
// According to their ***default configuration***, the cameras are
// set up for free-running continuous acquisition.
cameras.StartGrabbing();
```

Also, please read these comments from the code carefully and see if you correctly configure your network and parameters. I suggest you try with one camera first:

```
// Limits the amount of cameras used for grabbing.
// It is important to manage the available bandwidth when grabbing with 
// multiple cameras.
// This applies, for instance, if two GigE cameras are connected to the 
// same network adapter via a switch.
// To manage the bandwidth, the GevSCPD interpacket delay parameter and 
// the GevSCFTD transmission delay
// parameter can be set for each GigE camera device.
// The "Controlling Packet Transmission Timing with the Interpacket and 
// Frame Transmission Delays on Basler GigE Vision Cameras"
// Application Notes (AW000649xx000)
// provide more information about this topic.
// The bandwidth used by a FireWire camera device can be limited by 
// adjusting the packet size.
```

Comment: When i tried with each camera one by one it worked. And also in Pylon Viewer it worked too. But when it came to 2 cameras at one time it didn't.

Comment: OK. What about your network? How are they connected inside your local network?

Comment: @ Farhad Rahmanifard My 2 cameras connect to my computer by 2 3.0 USB cables

Comment: So there is no such network bottleneck. I am not sure if I can help here but may be able to help with trying to find the source of the problem. Please run two separate programs each connected to one of the cameras and see how they work. If they work smoothly, then there must be a problem in source code to handling two cameras. If not, then at least we know that the source code is fine.

Comment: Sorry for reply to you very late.I'm so busy with this stuff those days but I can happily to tell you it worked .I've fixed my source code after try doing what you told as above.Thousand thank you!!

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy to hear that. Please, close the question by changing its state to answered.